# Geth wallet confusion

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

So, I'm running my rig on the ethermine pool and I used the geth program to setup a wallet which acts as my "miner" name on ethermine.  When I click on my miner address I am taken to etherchain.org and it's shows my balance etc.  Now how the hell do I transfer that ether to a coinbase to poloniex?  I can't seem to do anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the private key from your address? You can use myetherwallet (https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) to create a transaction, sign it with the private key, and send it to another ether address (poloniex or wherever). If you do not have the private key from your address, you cannot access the ethereum that you mined.

Simple: Private key is the secret code from which the address is generated. So signing with the private key, means that you can prove that the address is yours. It is impossible to generate a private key from an address (the address is also sometimes called public key)

Answer (score 0):

If you have geth running and synchronized you can use [Ethereum Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

Comment: yeah, I can have it running I guess.  I'm in a pool, so I didn't think I needed to run geth..

Comment: The coins should appear wherever you specify you want them to go. This is not bound to the machine doing the work. True, if you sent them to an account from `geth` and `geth` has the signing key, then you could use `geth` to forward those ones. It's also possible to take the `keystore` or private key somewhere else.